# How to use click event in MaterialDesign:PackIcon in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I used `materialDesign:PackIkon` in my WPF application.

this is my code at xaml for the PackIcon

```
<ListViewItem Background="White" Height="55" >
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="CardMembership" MouseDown="PackIconMember_MouseDown" Height="40" Width="25" Foreground="#FF0959A8" />
             <Button  x:Name="btnMember" Click="btnMember_Click" Content="Member" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10" />
           </StackPanel>
  </ListViewItem>
```

I have a few `PackIcon` in my xaml. each of them in different listview.

what I want is when user click on the `Icon` it will process the event in `PackIconMember_MouseDown`

There is no error in my code above, the problem is sometimes the code work. I means when user click on the icon it will process the event. but sometimes user need to click multiple time for it to process the event. I don't know why this happen.

Any idea on what I should do with this ? or any suggestion to replace the `MouseDown` event.

[image: its only work when I click on icon with the blue color]

its only work when I click on icon with the blue color.
it does not working when I click on the white space that I show with the arrow. how can I do to make it work when user click anywhere on the icon ? is it possible ?

if I do inside button, the packIcon does not appear

```
 <Button Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" Height="20" Width="25" Margin="10">
    <materialDesign:PackIcon MouseDown="PackIconMember_MouseDown" TouchDown="PackIconMember_MouseDown" Kind="CardMembership" />
 </Button>
```

Comment: why don't you wrap the Icon inside a button ? and use a real click event ?

Comment: If you click in the same spot, the event should always get raised. What are you doing in the event handler?

Comment: @mm8 its only working when I click on the icon with the blue spot. the event handle is the event to go to another view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Background` property of the `PackIcon` to `Transparent`:

```
<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="CardMembership" MouseDown="PackIconMember_MouseDown" Height="40" Width="25" Foreground="#FF0959A8"
                         Background="Transparent" />
```

This should capture the clicks also on the "empty" parts of the icon.

Answer (score 1):

Make The Icon as Part of the Button Like:

```
<Button  x:Name="btnMember" Click="btnMember_Click" Content="Member" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10" >
     <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="CardMembership" Height="40" Width="25" Foreground="#FF0959A8" />
</Button
```

But you have to set the margin